# Django Gives The Same Response From MongoDB Even With Different Input-Values

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I started using Django recently.

I've integrated MongoDB using PyMongo module [pip3 install pymongo].

**My Problem:**

Django gives me the same data even after the database gets updated. Whenever I run some manipulations; like comparing the email entered by the user with that of existing email IDs in the database, I get the same result every time.

Looks like the result is getting cached.

**Urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage),
    path('register/', views.register),
]
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from pymongo import MongoClient
from django import http

def homepage(request):
    return (render(request, 'index.html'))

def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        client = MongoClient('mongodb://my_ip:27017/')
        db = client.trainingdb
        collection = db.data
        emailCheck = str(collection.find({"Email":email}))
        if emailCheck == "":
            dbData = {
            'Name': name,
            'Email': email,
            'Password': password
            }
            collection.insert_one(dbData)
            return http.HttpResponse("Success!")
        else:
            return http.HttpResponse("Email exists in database!")
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```

The `homepage` method is for index page or main page. The `register` method is for the registration page.

Here, I'm trying to check whether the email ID entered by the user pre-exists in the database or not.

**Test Cases:**

For the first time, I've entered an email ID that's already in the database, I got the expected result: `Email exists in database!`.

But for the second time, I've entered an email ID that's not in the database; but I get the same old result: `Email exists in database!`.

Is it due to caching or something like that?

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. Please read the question twice and understand my problem...

Comment: Hi Praneeth Karnena; there is no caching which would make the second query return incorrect results. It's probably best if you double-check your data, and both the code and the query you use to identify whether the item already exists or not; the examples in the question linked by Neil should be useful to you.

Comment: I have figured out that we can even use `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collection.find()` returns a Cursor instance. For some reason you are converting this to a string and comparing it to `""`. But even if the list is empty, `str()` of that will not be `""`, it will be something like `"<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7f10b69d0c50>"`. So the condition is never true.

There is no reason to convert to a string or compare with one. Instead, check the number of documents matched:

```
emailCheck = collection.find({"Email":email}).count()
if emailCheck == 0:
    ...
```